# Combine output of two mongo queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I'm using node.js and express, and I want to combine and then return the output of two mongodb queries from two different collections.
Each collection has data for a different user, and I want to display the data for all users in a list.

I tried doing

```
router.get('/dataAll', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('data1').find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        var firstQuery = items;
        console.log('first query:'+items);
        db.collection('data2').find().toArray(function(err, items2) {
            console.log('second query:'+items2);
            var itemsTotal=[];
            itemsTotal.concat(JSON.stringify(items));
            itemsTotal.concat(JSON.stringify(items2));
            console.log('combined query:'+itemsTotal);
            res.json(itemsTotal);
        });
    });
});
```

But I just get a blank array in `itemsTotal`.
How do I concatenate the outputs together?

Also, when I do `console.log('first query:'+items);`, it just outputs [object Object]. How do I make it show the real values that are being returned?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

```
router.get('/dataAll', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db, itemsTotal = [], s1,s2, closed = [false,false];
    var adding = function(data){
      itemsTotal.push(data);
    };
    var closing =function(i){
      closed[i] = true;
      if(closed[0]&&closed[1]) return res.json(itemsTotal);
    };
    s1 = db.collection('data').find().stream();
    s1.on('data', adding);
    s1.on('close',function(){ closing(0); });
    s2 = db.collection('data1').find().stream();
    s2.on('data', adding);
    s2.on('close',function(){ closing(1); });
});
```

Comment: I tried that http://pastebin.com/bw9dSyzW, but I got a '500: internal server error' on the GET request.